# Makefile: How can I make a macro value computed in one target available to another target?

Tags: macros, makefile, target

I'm trying to do this in my Makefile:

```
VAL=

TARGET1:
    VAL= ... #compute value of VAL
    #run some command that uses the value of VAL
TARGET2:
    $(MAKE) TARGET1
    #run other command that uses the value of VAL
```

But it turns out that value of VAL is reset when TARGET! completes in TARGET2. Thus the computed value of VAL is not available when I try to run the other command in TARGET2. Is there any way to keep the value computed in TARGET1? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a fundamental misconception.  The variable `VAL` that is set in the `TARGET1` recipe is not a make variable at all: it's a shell variable.  You can tell because if you change the syntax of the assignment to be something else that is still a valid make variable assignment but is not a valid shell variable assignment, like:

```
TARGET1:
        VAL := foo
```

it will give you a syntax error.  Basically in make, any recipe line (lines after a target that begin with a TAB character) are not interpreted by make at all: they're passed to a shell that make invokes.  Nothing that happens in that shell can have any effect on the value of make variables, etc. of course.

You don't give us much detail.  You don't say whether the command uses the variable from the environment or via the command line.  You don't say what version of make you're using.  If it's GNU make, you have a number of options.  The simplest one is to set the value always; if it requires shell syntax you can use the shell function:

```
VAL := $(shell #compute value of VAL)

TARGET1:
        #run some command that uses $(VAL)
TARGET2:
        #run another command that uses $(vAL)
```

Before we give you more possibilities we need to understand the requirements: if you HAVE to have the value set in `TARGET1` we need to know why, before we can offer possible solutions.